# Trove hash maps not implementing hashCode

Tags: java, hash, trove4j

I stumbled across the issue with `TObjectDoubleHashMap` of trove. The version 2.0.2 doesn't override the [`hashCode`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.0.2/trove4j-2.0.2-javadoc.jar!/gnu/trove/TObjectDoubleHashMap.html) method.

More recent versions of trove (3.0.0) include the [`hashCode`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectDoubleHashMap.html#hashCode%28%29).

Note, that the `equals` method is overriden in both versions.

Why wasn't the `hashCode` method overriden in the version 2?  Maybe the contract for overriding `hashCode`/`equals` was introduced after the trove maps were written originally? Or is it simply a violation of the contract and a bug that was fixed later? I'd be very surprised if it's a bug and not a feature, because how come the class that mostly deals with hashing not override `hashCode` when it has `equals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe the contract for overriding `hashCode`/`equals` was introduced after the trove maps were written originally?

No.  That was present way back.  I believe at least as early as 1.1, but I can't find anything earlier than [1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) docs.

> Or is it simply a violation of the contract and a bug?

Yes.  It is a violation of the contract.  Note that `java.util.Map` has its own extra equality/hashCode contract above and beyond `java.lang.Object`, which is knowingly violated by `IdentityHashMap` and a few others.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> ```
> public boolean equals(Object o)
> ```
>
> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns `true` if the given object is also a map and the two `Map`s represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps t1 and t2 represent the same mappings if `t1.entrySet().equals(t2.entrySet())`. **This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `Map` interface.**